# Mysql not updating using following code dont know why

Tags: php, mysql

> Why it is not working

```
   $sql="UPDATE studentrecord
    SET (fnam, lnam, rollno,stats)  =  ('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[rollno]','$_POST[stats]')
 WHERE rollno = '$_POST[rollno]'";
```

Comment: your query is not correct change it to set fname = '$_POST[fname]', second = second....

Comment: [**SQL INJECTION!**](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 3):

the query should be

```
$sql="UPDATE studentrecord
SET fnam = '$_POST[fname]', lnam = '$_POST[lname]', rollno = '$_POST[rollno]',stats  = '$_POST[stats]'
WHERE rollno = '$_POST[rollno]'";
```

Comment: @TeAmo Accepting answer is good habit, when it helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Query , Change it to this :-

```
 $sql="UPDATE studentrecord
SET fnam = '$_POST[fname]', lnam = '$_POST[lname]', rollno = '$_POST[rollno]',stats =  '$_POST[stats]'
 WHERE rollno = '$_POST[rollno]'";
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL is as followed:

```
$sql = "
  UPDATE studentrecord
  SET fnam='$_POST[fname]', lnam='$_POST[lname]', states='$_POST[stats]'
  WHERE rollno = '$_POST[rollno]'
";
```

I also removed `SET rollno='$_POST[rollno]'` because that variable isn't changing and this is not necessary.

Refer to the documentation to see how UPDATE differs from INSERT:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html